# I have a list of 9 random numbers, how do I find duplicates with RegEx?

Tags: regex, parsing, random, numbers, pcre

The numbers are all between 1 and 3 digits long and separated by spaces. I'm terrible with RegEx and don't even know where to start.

Example:

```
59, 5, 53, 53, 545, 55, 545, 56, 5
```

I don't need to actually know which items are duplicates - just if there are any at all.

3 Great answers, thanks a lot.

Comment: Why regex? It might not be best tool for the job.

Comment: It has to be regex, unfortunately. It's for a scripting engine that doesn't support anything else.

Comment: Do you have to _find_ the duplicates with Regex, or can you get each number and compare it with the others in a loop?

Comment: A scripting engine that doesn't support anything else? Is it simply _a regex engine_?

Comment: You should give *lots* more information about the restrictions you have for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "back-references" to solve this...

```
/(^|[^0-9])([0-9]+)(?=[^0-9]).*[^0-9]\2([^0-9]|$)/
```

The meaning is

1. `(^|[0-9])` Start of the string OR a non-numeric
2. `([0-9]+)` one or more digits
3. `(?=[^0-9])` a non-numeric char, but don't take it
4. `.*`anything
5. `[^0-9]` a non-numeric char
6. `\2` the same thing we found at 2 (it's the second parenthesized expression)
7. `($|[^0-9])` End of string OR a non-numeric char

the reason for which a zero-width lookahead assertion `(?=...)` is needed in (3) is because the two copies could be one right after the other in the sequence (with only one non-numeric character between them).

All the non-numeric/start-of-string/end-of-string trickery is needed because you don't want `"1,2,3,4,33,9"` to match as duplicate because the beginning of `33` matches the `3` (you only want to consider full numbers, i.e. take all the consecutive digits to do the check).

Answer (score 2):

> Re: I don't need to actually know which items are duplicates - just if there are any at all.

It will match in case when string has duplicate numbers,

```
/(\b\d+\b)(?=.*?\b\1\b)/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\b(\d+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/7

Answer (score -2):

Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this.

Something like this Perl one-liner perhaps?

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -E"say join ', ', uniq shift =~ /\d+/g" "59, 5, 53, 53, 545, 55, 545, 56, 5"
```

**output**

```
59, 5, 53, 545, 55, 56
```